# Is there a better way to do 'complex' list comprehension?

Tags: python, performance, format, list-comprehension

I tend to use list comprehension a lot in Python because I think it is a clean way to generate lists, but often I find myself coming back a week later and thinking to myself **"What the hell did I do this for?!"** and it's a 70+ character nested conditional list comprehension statement. I am wondering if it gets to a certain point if I should break it out into if/elif/else, and the performance impact, if any of doing so.

**My current circumstance:**

Returned structure from call is a list of tuples. I need to cast it to a list, some values need to be cleaned up, and I need to strip the last element from the list.

e.g.

```
[(val1, ' ', 'ChangeMe', 'RemoveMe),
 (val1, ' ', 'ChangeMe', 'RemoveMe),
 (val1, ' ', 'ChangeMe', 'RemoveMe)]
```

So in this case, I want to remove `RemoveMe`, replace all `' '` with `''` and replace `ChangeMe` with `val2`. I know it is a lot of changes, but the data I am returned is terrible sometimes and I have no control over what is coming to me as a response.

I currently have something like:

```
response = cursor.fetchall()
response = [['' if item == ' ' else item if item != 'ChangeMe' else 'val2' for item in row][:-1] for row in response]`
```

Is a nested multi-conditional comprehension statement frowned upon? I know stylistically Python prefers to be very readable, but also compact and not as verbose.

Any tips or info would be greatly appreciated. Thanks all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python favors one-liner, on the sole condition that these make the code **more readable**, and not that it complicates it.

In this case, you use two nested  list comprehension, two adjacent ternary operators, a list slicing, all of this on a single line which exceeds the 100 characters... It is everything but readable.

Sometimes it's better to use a classic for loop.

```
result = []
for val, space, item, remove in response:
    result.append([val, '', 'val2'])
```

And then you realise you can write it as a list comprehension much more comprehensible (assuming your filter condition is simple):

```
result = [[val, '', 'val2'] for val, *_ in response]
```

Remember, every code is **written once**, but it is **read many times**.

Comment: That short, comprehensible list comprehension though! +1 :)

Comment: Appreciate the input, thanks! Yeah that was pretty much what I was getting at - list comprehensions can get complicated quick with just a few conditionals and become unreadable. I agree that a for loop + simple comprehension is much more approachable.

Comment: partial unpacking. the sexiness

Answer (score 0):

This is one quick way you could do a list-comprehension making use of a dictionary for mapping items:

```
response = [('val1', ' ', 'ChangeMe', 'RemoveMe'), ('val1', ' ', 'ChangeMe', 'RemoveMe'), ('val1', ' ', 'ChangeMe', 'RemoveMe')]
map_dict = {' ': '', 'ChangeMe': 'val2', 'val1': 'val1'}

response = [tuple(map_dict[x] for x in tupl if x != 'RemoveMe') for tupl in response]
# [('val1', '', 'val2'), ('val1', '', 'val2'), ('val1', '', 'val2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can easily extend to multiple changed values by adding in lookup_dict

response = [('val1', ' ', 'ChangeMe', 'RemoveMe'), ('val1', ' ', 'ChangeMe', 'RemoveMe'), ('val1', ' ', 'ChangeMe', 'RemoveMe')]
lookup_dict = {' ': '', 'ChangeMe': 'val2'}

[ [lookup_dict[item] if item in lookup_dict else item for item in row][:-1] for row in response]